# I want to make a scatterplot of earnings vs education but it shows error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a scatter plot of earnings vs education for my statistical models class but it says "invalid character in identifier" but when I check on the txt file the characters "earnings" and "education" are both present. Could you help me please?

```
mod = smf.ols(formula=’education~earnings, data=mydata)
res = mod.fit()
res.summary()
beta=res.params 
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(mydata["education"],mydata["earnings"],color="black") 
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(mydata["education"], res.fittedvalues, "r") 
matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel("earnings")
matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel("education") 
matplotlib.pyplot.title("Scatterplot earnings versus education") 
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Hey Nesrine. That error is complaining about an invalid character in a variable name. If you post the traceback (the full error) it should be possible to see where that is. Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14844830/754456

Comment: Hello @mfizp , the error is on education but when I check the txt file it's in there. Here's the full error message:

  File "/var/folders/vj/pxgh1vcx2zsf_cs2hld5dxvm0000gn/T/ipykernel_9043/3398938949.py", line 3
    mod = smf.ols(formula=’education~earnings, data=mydata)
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the quotation mark after the `=` on this line:

```py
mod = smf.ols(formula=’education~earnings, data=mydata)
```

This is confusing Python as it's not a valid variable name. The formula should be passed as a string, with a opening & closing single/double quote.

```py
mod = smf.ols(formula='education~earnings', data=mydata)
```

Perhaps something got mixed up when copy-pasting it?