# Cannot copy and paste code into ipython3 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, ipython, newline, copy-paste

Suppose I want to copy and paste code into the ipython3 terminal on Windows. This is what usually happens:

[image]

See a video here: https://youtu.be/-cMsy8sEXE0

As you can see, there are these `^M` characters appearing, and I have no idea what they are. Interestingly, as you can see in the video, the results are not the same when copying and pasting from Excel vs. Notepad. Any idea what is happening here? Is my only bet to write an autohotkey script that modifies the contents of the clipboard to paste something `ipython3.exe` can understand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid character in identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844687/invalid-character-in-identifier)

Comment: I'd guess that  `^M` is the same as `␍` (U+000D,  *Carriage Return (CR)*)…